# Merge and Format in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

So I am learning Pandas and I am having trouble merging two data frames.May be it is more of a formatting problem but even after lots of trying researching I am not getting it.

Let say we have two sessions of Math tutoring and we want to find out which are the students that attended both.

Dataframe A.

`Id  Subject    Students_A
1      Maths        Ron
2      Maths        Harry
3      Maths       Hermionie
4      Maths        Draco`

Dataframe B.

`Id Subject     Students_B
1   Maths       Harry
2   Maths       Draco
3   Maths       Neville`

Now I did this in jupyter notebook:

`df_common = pd.merge(df_A,df_B,left_on='studentA', right_on='studentB', how='outer')`

and got this :

`Id  Subject_x     StudentA     Subject_y  StudentB
1   Maths         Ron          Nan       Nan
2   Maths        Harry         Maths     Harry
3   Maths        Hermionie     Nan       Nan
4   Maths         Draco         Maths    Draco
5   Nan           Nan          Maths     Neville`

However I want something like this:

`Id  Subject     StudentA      StudentB
1   Maths         Ron           Nan
2   Maths        Harry          Harry
3   Maths        Hermionie      Nan
4   Maths        Draco         Draco
5   Maths         Nan           Neville`

What am I doing wrong?Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge on `Students` AND `Subject`:

```
df1.merge(df2, how="outer",
               left_on=["Subject","Students_A"], 
               right_on=["Subject","Students_B"])

  Subject Students_A Students_B
0   Maths        Ron        NaN
1   Maths      Harry      Harry
2   Maths  Hermionie        NaN
3   Maths      Draco      Draco
4   Maths        NaN    Neville
```

Note: Assumes `Id` can be used as an index, e.g.

```
df1 = pd.read_clipboard(index_col="Id")

   Subject Students_A
Id                   
1    Maths        Ron
2    Maths      Harry
3    Maths  Hermionie
4    Maths      Draco
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this after the merge statement:

```
df_common["Subject"] = df_common["Subject_x"].fillna(df_common["Subject_y"])
df_common = df_common.drop(["Subject_x", "Subject_y"], 1)
```

So basically when you performed the join, Subject was re-named to Subject_x and Subject_y so that you can distinguish them. In order to join those columns, create a new column named Subject that accepts the non-Null values in Subject_x and where Null, pulls in the values from Subject_y. Then drop Subject_x and Subject_y

Comment: `df_common.drop(["Subject_x", "Subject_y"],axis=1)`

Comment: Aah , Why didn't I think of that.I thought there is someway we could just do it with merge statement.